# How to set height of a view in percent using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-guideline

Currently I'm  learning `ConstraintLayout`

below is my code that i have tried so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.PhaseListActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/tvAnimText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/knowledge_bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/greenColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_100ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="1" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Scrollbale view below my videoView"
                    android:textColor="#ff00"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Scrollbale view below my videoView"
                    android:textColor="#ff00"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Scrollbale view below my videoView"
                    android:textColor="#ff00"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/greenColor"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Fixed Bottombar"
            android:textColor="#ff00"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want don't want use nested `LinearLayout` inside `ConstraintLayout`

Also in above layout my `NestedScrollView` is not scrolling

I want to create this type of screen using `ConstraintLayout`

My expected OUTPUT

[image]

I have tried to set `Guideline`  but it didn't work for me, because i don't know how to use `Guideline` in above layout

Can anybody help me create this screen only using `ConstraintLayout`

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: Not clear what you trying to archive? Your current design is similar like your shared screen design.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati yes i want create that layout without using nested `LinearLayout`

Comment: You mean you want archive same result with only constraintlayout right ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati right please check updated question

Comment: @Goku, may i know why you use NestedScrollView?

Comment: @PRIYAPARASHAR because i need to  some other views below VideoView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after looking at your xml file, I've come up with solution to get rid of nested `LinearLayout` hierarchy in below solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_bottom_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.85"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/tvAnimText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/knowledge_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/greenColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_100ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/myVideoView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/myVideoView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/myVideoView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/myVideoView"
            tools:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Scrollbale view below my videoView"
            android:textColor="#ff00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/myVideoView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Scrollbale view below my videoView"
            android:textColor="#ff00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Scrollbale view below my videoView"
            android:textColor="#ff00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv2" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_bottom_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Fixed Bottombar"
    android:textColor="#ff00"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know if there's any query in comments. For your fixed bottombar `TextView`, now you can change height percent to whatever you want to change it's height dynamically.

Comment: hey thanks for the replay for some reason `Scrollbale view below my videoView` is not visible and also `NestedScrollView` is not scrolling

Comment: @Goku Please checkout updated xml code, I've made some changes related to `VideoView` *(Added height percent to it)*.

Comment: sorry for the late replay, its working fine after some changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for bottom View which remove your Nested LinearLayout :

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Fixed Bottombar"
            android:textColor="#ff00"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:padding="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```